# GETS - C is not working for me

Tags: c, function, printf, gets

I am having trouble with inserting string in to char variable. Problem appeares when I put it into function. When I debug my program, it displays `printf` but it skipes `gets`

here is my code:

```
int uloz(SPRAVA *p){

    char string[200];

    printf("Your message here: ");
    gets(string);
    printf("You have entered: %s", string);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First: **Never use `gets`**; it's extremely dangerous (and has therefore been removed from the language). Second: can you give more details of what happens and what you expect to happen?

Comment: I want to store string for ex. "My name is Mario.", and I want to include spaces.

Comment: And what happens? `gets` (urgh) and `fgets` have no problem reading spaces, so your problem must be something else.

Comment: yes fgets is reading from file... but I want to enter some string in my application and store it in file

Comment: `fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin);` reads a line or at most 199 characters (one for the 0-terminator) from standard input and stores them in `string`. You can then write it to a file with `fprintf(file_pointer, "%s", string);`. If you do that, what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `scanf(" %30[^\n]%*c",string);`

1. `[^\n]` will accept anything till `\n`.
2. `30` will limit the length of number of characters to max 30.
3. initial `space(' ')` will consume any `\n` already in stdin stream. (optional & i have not verified it)
4. & Finally, `%*c` will consume `\n` pressed after entering string.

I think, `scanf(" %30[^\n]%*[^\n]%*c",string);` would be a good option, to discard remaining characters (after 30) that were entered. However this is completely unverified. Just added as a possible idea. Test before use. :-)

Comment: +1 This goes with the general advice 'Don't mix (f)gets and scanf' -- if you're using scanf elsewhere, use scanf here too.

Answer (score 1):

There's a newline in the stdio buffer (left over by some previous `scanf`) so `gets` is immediately satisfied.

There's no easy way to fix it but you could try discarding input, before the `fgets`:

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    /* discard the character */;
```

The true solution is to avoid mixing `scanf` and `fgets`.

---

Use `fgets` instead of `gets`.

Comment: More specifically, if you are always expecting entire lines, but still want to get ints etc out of them, then use fgets to read a line, and parse it with sscanf. Also not just scanf, but also getchar (used in question code) can be problematic.